# SQL query based on number of digits

Tags: sql

New to SQL.

I am trying to pull all the records where "Customer Number" is a 12-digit number. In the "Customer Number" column, there are only 9 digit or 12 digit numbers. I need only the customers who's "Customer Number" is 12 digits. Seems straight forward but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Is "Customer Number" a numerical based data type or a string based data type?

Comment: If it's a numeric type use `> 999999999`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `len()`/`length()` (depending on your database):

```
select t.*
from t
where len(customer_number) = 12
```

You can also use `like`:

```
where customer_number like '____________'  -- exactly 12 underscores
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select customer_num from
xx_customers
where length(customer_num)=12;
```

`Length` function can be used in where condition